# React Context Api - A Context Passed through Context Provider is yet not able to accessible by Child Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, components, react-context

I have a component **ExpandableCard** and created its context **ExpandableCardContext** and context provider **ExpandableCardProvider**. Then I called the provider from some **ParentComponent** by passing a prop "handleCloseExpandableCard"(an arrow function) and also another prop "component" have value a **ChildComponent** which gets called from **ExpandableCard**. The problem is that **ChildComponent** doesn't receive "handleCloseExpandableCard" as a prop.

**ParentComponent**

[image]
**ExpandableCardProvider
**
[image]
**ExpandableCardContext
**
[image]
**ExpandableCard**
it calls the component(ParcelCardProvider) passed from "ParentComponent" and that ParcelCardProvider is not receiving "handleCloseExpandCard" as a prop.
[image]

This is the Error I'm getting.
[image: Image With error]

My Guess is that parcel card is being called as a prop outside that context but at the same time it's wrapped inside the Context Provider component. Anybody here with help?
Much Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code as plain text instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this one.
I was trying to import handleCloseExpandableCard as

```
const [handleCloseExpandableCard] = useContext(ExpandableCardContext);
```

but actually it needed to be import like this

```
const [, , handleCloseExpandableCard] = useContext(ExpandableCardContext);
```